# Use The current styles in the userstyles.css in Joplin without the need the need to reopening Joplin

Tags: tailwind-css

I was lately trying to use tailwindcss inside Joplin. So the idea basically is to watch files inside the `~/.config/joplin-desktop` with the tailwind script and store the generated CSS in `userstyles.css` which lives in the same directory.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{md,html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
   plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ]
}
```

```css
//main.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I run the tailwind watch script like this :

```sh
$tailwind -i main.css -o userstyles.css --watch

#tailwind is the standalone binary provided by tailwind which I installed globally
```

**The css is generated to the userstyles.css, but the issue is that I need to close Joplin and Reopen it Again in order for the  styles to take effect. Is there away to make joplin use the styles in the userstyels.css with the need of reopening Joplin**

I appreciate your time.

the expected Behaviour is the styles to be applied on the fly.